# Strongly typed url action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, expression, func

I've read multiple posts and blogs similar to

[Delegate-based strongly-typed URL generation in ASP.NET MVC](https://maxtoroq.github.io/2013/04/delegate-based-strongly-typed-url.html)

But none of them really quite do what I'd like to do.  Currently I have a hybrid approach like:

```
// shortened for Brevity
public static Exts
{  
  public string Action(this UrlHelper url, 
    Expression<Func<T, ActionResult>> expression)
    where T : ControllerBase
  {
    return Exts.Action(url, expression, null);
  }

  public string Action(this UrlHelper url, 
    Expression<Func<T, ActionResult>> expression,
    object routeValues)
    where T : ControllerBase
  {
    string controller;
    string action;

    // extension method 
    expression.GetControllerAndAction(out controller, out action);

    var result = url.Action(action, controller, routeValues);

    return result;
  }
}
```

Works great if you're controller methods don't have any parameters:

```
public class MyController : Controller 
{
  public ActionResult MyMethod()
  {
    return null;
  }
  public ActionResult MyMethod2(int id)
  {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Then I can:

```
Url.Action<MyController>(c => c.MyMethod())
```

But if my method takes a parameter, then I have to pass a value (that I would never use):

```
Url.Action<MyController>(c => c.MyMethod2(-1), new { id = 99 })
```

So the question is there a way to change the extension method to still require the first parameter to be a method defined on type `T` that *does* check to make sure the return parameter is an `ActionResult` without actually specifying a parameter, something like:

```
Url.Action<MyController>(c => c.MyMethod2, new { id = 99 })
```

So this would pass *a pointer to the method* (like a reflection `MethodInfo`) instead of the `Func<>`, so it wouldn't care about parameters.  What would that signature look like if it was possible?

Comment: With `c.MyMethod2` you're pointing to a method _group_, any of which can return something else... But I'm fairly sure I've seen libraries that enable this. Perhaps you can do some reflection magic and check in `GetControllerAndAction` that the method of the group matching the provided parameters does indeed return `ActionResult`. This will not exactly give you the compile-time safety you're looking for, but you shouldn't have non-actionmethods as public methods in your controller anyway.

Comment: `c => c.MyMethod2` can't be cast from `Method Group` to non-delegate type `ActionResult`.

Comment: You're right of course, that'll only work in the current controller, not in the view. Why aren't you using `c => c.MyMethod2(99)` instead (using `MethodCallExpression.Arguments` to get the arguments)?

Comment: Let me think about that... I intentionally removed that code because it seems ambiguous: `c => c.MyMethod(99), new { id = 98 }`... but maybe I don't need route values at that point...  I'm trying to think of a reason I would need a route value...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this:

```
c => c.MyMethod2
```

Because that is a method group. Any method in a method group can return void or anything else, so the compiler won't allow it:

> ```
> Error CS0428  Cannot convert method group '...' to non-delegate type '...'
> ```

There may be *a* method in the group returning an `ActionMethod`, or none. You need to decide that.

But you don't have to provide a method group anyway. You can just use your existing signature, minus the `object routeValues`, and call it like this:

```
Url.Action<MyController>(c => c.MyMethod(99))
```

Then in your method, you can use the `MethodInfo methodCallExpression.Method` to obtain the method parameter names, and the `methodCallExpression.Arguments` to get the arguments.

Then your next problem is creating the anonymous object at runtime. Luckily you don't have to, as `Url.Action()` also has an overload accepting a `RouteValueDictionary`.

Zip the parameters and arguments together into a dictionary, create a `RouteValueDictionary` from that, and pass that to `Url.Action()`:

```
var methodCallExpression = expression.Body as MethodCallExpression;
if (methodCallExpression == null)
{                
    throw new ArgumentException("Not a MethodCallExpression", "expression");
}

var methodParameters = methodCallExpression.Method.GetParameters();
var routeValueArguments = methodCallExpression.Arguments.Select(EvaluateExpression);

var rawRouteValueDictionary = methodParameters.Select(m => m.Name)
                            .Zip(routeValueArguments, (parameter, argument) => new
                            {
                                parameter,
                                argument
                            })
                            .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.parameter, kvp => kvp.argument);

var routeValueDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(rawRouteValueDictionary);

// action and controller obtained through your logic 

return url.Action(action, controller, routeValueDictionary);
```

The `EvaluateExpression` method very naively compiles and invokes every non-constant expression, so may prove to be horribly slow in practice:

```
private static object EvaluateExpression(Expression expression)
{
    var constExpr = expression as ConstantExpression;
    if (constExpr != null)
    {
        return constExpr.Value;
    }

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(expression);
    var compiled = lambda.Compile();
    return compiled.DynamicInvoke();
}
```

---

However, in the [Microsoft ASP.NET MVC Futures package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Futures/) there's the convenient `ExpressionHelper.GetRouteValuesFromExpression(expr)‌​`, which also handles routing and areas. Your entire method then can be replaced with:

```
var routeValues = Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Internal.ExpressionHelper.GetRouteValuesFromExpression<T>(expression);
return url.Action(routeValues["Action"], routeValues["Controller"], routeValues);
```

It uses a cached expression compiler internally, so it works for all use cases and you won't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: If they aren't a `ConstantExpression` wouldn't I have to compile and execute that expression to get a value for the `RouteValueDictionary`?

Comment: I can't use the Futures package, but I can just `compile()` the expression and use the value as object hopefully..

Comment: @Erik I've done that, see edit - and caveat. It works for me with constants, method calls and member access, but you'll really have to test it yourself. I think you'll also have to look for an Area attribute on the controller and add that to the `routeValueDictionary` if you want it to work with areas.

Comment: what I'm going to do is check the controller's namespace.  If I get crazy I can validate it against AreaRegistration :)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative for other projects, I've recently started using [nameof](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof).

```
Url.Action(nameof(MyController.MyMethod), nameof(MyController), new { id = 99 })
```

the only real downside is that they can be mixed and produce incorrect results post compile:

```
Url.Action(nameof(SomeOtherController.MyMethod), nameof(MyController), new { id = 99 })
```

The controllers *don't match* but I don't think it's a big deal.  It still throws and error during compiling when the controller name or the method name changes and isn't updated else where in code.

Answer (score -1):

Ivaylo Kenov created a Nuget package [AspNet.Mvc.TypedRouting](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNet.Mvc.TypedRouting/) ([Github repository](https://github.com/ivaylokenov/AspNet.Mvc.TypedRouting))

Just call the `AddTypedRouting` extension method **after** the `AddMvc` one

```cs
services.AddMvc().AddTypedRouting();
```

Or if you're developing a web API:

```cs
services.AddControllers().AddTypedRouting();
```

Then you can get URLs with an expression as you'd like to

```cs
Url.Action<FooController>(c => c.Get(fooId));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I *didn't* want to do; I don't want to pass the required parameters.

Comment: @ErikPhilips That's not what you said in your question. You said you wanted something like `Url.Action<MyController>(c => c.MyMethod2, new { id = 99 })` where you pass the `id` parameter but avoid passing an unused value `-1` like in `Url.Action<MyController>(c => c.MyMethod2(-1), new { id = 99 })`.
I think that's *exactly* answering your answer

Comment: So the question is there a way to change the extension method to still require the first parameter to be a method defined on type T that does check to make sure the return parameter is an ActionResult **without actually specifying a parameter**, something like: